# How to interpret kernel panics?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, linux-kernel

I'm new to linux kernel and could barely understand how to debug kernel panics. I have this error below and I don't know where in the C code should I start checking. I was thinking maybe I could echo what functions are being called so I could check where/at what particular function is this null pointer dereferenced. What print function should I use ? How do you interpret the error message below?

```
Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 0000000d
pgd = c7bdc000
[0000000d] *pgd=4785f031, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 17 [#1] PREEMPT
Modules linked in: bcm5892_secdom_fw(P) bcm5892_lcd snd_bcm5892 msr bcm5892_sci bcm589x_ohci_p12 bcm5892_skeypad hx_decoder(P) pinnacle hx_memalloc(P) bcm_udc_dwc scsi_mod g_serial sd_mod usb_storage
CPU: 0    Tainted: P           (2.6.27.39-WR3.0.2ax_standard #1)
PC is at __kmalloc+0x70/0xdc
LR is at __kmalloc+0x48/0xdc
pc : [c0098cc8]    lr : [c0098ca0]    psr: 20000093
sp : c7a9fd50  ip : c03a4378  fp : c7a9fd7c
r10: bf0708b4  r9 : c7a9e000  r8 : 00000040
r7 : bf06d03c  r6 : 00000020  r5 : a0000093  r4 : 0000000d
r3 : 00000000  r2 : 00000094  r1 : 00000020  r0 : c03a4378
Flags: nzCv  IRQs off  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Control: 00c5387d  Table: 47bdc008  DAC: 00000015
Process sh (pid: 1088, stack limit = 0xc7a9e260)
Stack: (0xc7a9fd50 to 0xc7aa0000)
fd40:                                     c7a6a1d0 00000020 c7a9fd7c c7ba8fc0
fd60: 00000040 c7a6a1d0 00000020 c71598c0 c7a9fd9c c7a9fd80 bf06d03c c0098c64
fd80: c71598c0 00000003 c7a6a1d0 bf06c83c c7a9fdbc c7a9fda0 bf06d098 bf06d008
fda0: c7159880 00000000 c7a6a2d8 c7159898 c7a9fde4 c7a9fdc0 bf06d130 bf06d078
fdc0: c79ca000 c7159880 00000000 00000000 c7afbc00 c7a9e000 c7a9fe0c c7a9fde8
fde0: bf06d4b4 bf06d0f0 00000000 c79fd280 00000000 0f700000 c7a9e000 00000241
fe00: c7a9fe3c c7a9fe10 c01c37b4 bf06d300 00000000 c7afbc00 00000000 00000000
fe20: c79cba84 c7463c78 c79fd280 c7473b00 c7a9fe6c c7a9fe40 c00a184c c01c35e4
fe40: 00000000 c7bb0005 c7a9fe64 c79fd280 c7463c78 00000000 c00a1640 c785e380
fe60: c7a9fe94 c7a9fe70 c009c438 c00a164c c79fd280 c7a9fed8 c7a9fed8 00000003
fe80: 00000242 00000000 c7a9feb4 c7a9fe98 c009c614 c009c2a4 00000000 c7a9fed8
fea0: c7a9fed8 00000000 c7a9ff64 c7a9feb8 c00aa6bc c009c5e8 00000242 000001b6
fec0: 000001b6 00000241 00000022 00000000 00000000 c7a9fee0 c785e380 c7473b00
fee0: d8666b0d 00000006 c7bb0005 00000300 00000000 00000000 00000001 40002000
ff00: c7a9ff70 c79b10a0 c79b10a0 00005402 00000003 c78d69c0 ffffff9c 00000242
ff20: 000001b6 c79fd280 c7a9ff64 c7a9ff38 c785e380 c7473b00 00000000 00000241
ff40: 000001b6 ffffff9c 00000003 c7bb0000 c7a9e000 00000000 c7a9ff94 c7a9ff68
ff60: c009c128 c00aa380 4d18b5f0 08000000 00000000 00071214 0007128c 00071214
ff80: 00000005 c0027ee4 c7a9ffa4 c7a9ff98 c009c274 c009c0d8 00000000 c7a9ffa8
ffa0: c0027d40 c009c25c 00071214 0007128c 0007128c 00000241 000001b6 00000000
ffc0: 00071214 0007128c 00071214 00000005 00073580 00000003 000713e0 400010d0
ffe0: 00000001 bef0c7b8 000269cc 4d214fec 60000010 0007128c 00000000 00000000
Backtrace:
[<c0098c58>] (__kmalloc+0x0/0xdc) from [<bf06d03c>] (gs_alloc_req+0x40/0x70 [g_serial]) r8:c71598c0 r7:00000020 r6:c7a6a1d0 r5:00000040 r4:c7ba8fc0
[<bf06cffc>] (gs_alloc_req+0x0/0x70 [g_serial]) from [<bf06d098>] (gs_alloc_requests+0x2c/0x78 [g_serial]) r7:bf06c83c r6:c7a6a1d0 r5:00000003 r4:c71598c0
[<bf06d06c>] (gs_alloc_requests+0x0/0x78 [g_serial]) from [<bf06d130>] (gs_start_io+0x4c/0xac [g_serial]) r7:c7159898 r6:c7a6a2d8 r5:00000000 r4:c7159880
[<bf06d0e4>] (gs_start_io+0x0/0xac [g_serial]) from [<bf06d4b4>] (gs_open+0x1c0/0x224 [g_serial]) r9:c7a9e000 r8:c7afbc00 r7:00000000 r6:00000000 r5:c7159880 r4:c79ca000
[<bf06d2f4>] (gs_open+0x0/0x224 [g_serial]) from [<c01c37b4>] (tty_open+0x1dc/0x314)
[<c01c35d8>] (tty_open+0x0/0x314) from [<c00a184c>] (chrdev_open+0x20c/0x22c)
[<c00a1640>] (chrdev_open+0x0/0x22c) from [<c009c438>] (__dentry_open+0x1a0/0x2b8) r8:c785e380 r7:c00a1640 r6:00000000 r5:c7463c78 r4:c79fd280
[<c009c298>] (__dentry_open+0x0/0x2b8) from [<c009c614>] (nameidata_to_filp+0x38/0x50)
[<c009c5dc>] (nameidata_to_filp+0x0/0x50) from [<c00aa6bc>] (do_filp_open+0x348/0x6f4) r4:00000000
[<c00aa374>] (do_filp_open+0x0/0x6f4) from [<c009c128>] (do_sys_open+0x5c/0x170)
[<c009c0cc>] (do_sys_open+0x0/0x170) from [<c009c274>] (sys_open+0x24/0x28) r8:c0027ee4 r7:00000005 r6:00071214 r5:0007128c r4:00071214
[<c009c250>] (sys_open+0x0/0x28) from [<c0027d40>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x2c)
Code: e59c4080 e59c8090 e3540000 159c308c (17943103)
---[ end trace be196e7cee3cb1c9 ]---
note: sh[1088] exited with preempt_count 2
process '-/bin/sh' (pid 1088) exited. Scheduling for restart.

Welcome to Wind River Linux
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the error is in kmalloc (topmost line in the backtrace) it probably means that the memory allocator is failing. Common causes include double free()ing memory or otherwise corrupting the memory allocator structures.

Since the previous frames in the backtrace all belong to the module g_serial, I may suspect that's the culprit.

I'd suggest getting the debugging symbols for the kernel and modules so that you should be able to have the source code files and lines displayed in the backtrace. That will help a lot.

Comment: you know what? I just echoed all the functions where it passes and you were right, it stops at kmalloc of the function gs_alloc_req. Is there anything we could to prevent this from happening? like checking "something" first before doing kmalloc? I tried checking if there's any double freeing of memory, maybe I just overlooked at some code... It's hard to check as well whether you have corrupted the memory or not... :(

Comment: yeah well the backtrace you posted already listed the functions that led to the crash... so it was kinda easy!
if you don't really have a clue of what it may be going wrong, then your best bet is getting in touch with the maintainer of the module and provide him with all the info he needs to reproduce the panic.

Comment: now I'm confused. I just recreated it and now I've got a different backtrace block.. :(

Comment: Backtrace:
[<c00986b8>] (kmem_cache_alloc+0x0/0x94) from [<c004f05c>] (alloc_pid+0x20/0x39c)
 r7:c78fc640 r6:c7ad98c0 r5:00000000 r4:00000000
[<c004f03c>] (alloc_pid+0x0/0x39c) from [<c0039c3c>] (copy_process+0x970/0xff4)
[<c00392cc>] (copy_process+0x0/0xff4) from [<c003a3e8>] (do_fork+0x128/0x364)
[<c003a2c0>] (do_fork+0x0/0x364) from [<c002bf94>] (sys_clone+0x34/0x3c)
[<c002bf60>] (sys_clone+0x0/0x3c) from [<c0027d40>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x2c)
Code: e5904080 e5906090 e3540000 1590308c (17943103)
---[ end trace 79f1dda17148ede1 ]---

Comment: The problem is always in a function that deals with memory allocation (kmem_cache_alloc), but this time is panicking during fork(). It defintiely smells like kernel structure corruption. As I already said, you're best bet is getting in touch with the maintainers and helping them reproduce the panic.

Comment: Keep in mind that kernel strcuture corruption is serious business: best-case scenario you get a kernel panic; worst-case scenario you get a fully exploitable security hole. If that machine is publicly network-reachable you should **disable immediately** the g_serial module and get in touch with the maintainer.

Answer (score 3):

It's frequent for a memory-allocator bug to show up at random places, because the code that *inserted* (freed) the memory block in the allocation system is faulty. Anybody coming next and trying to allocate that block will trigger the error, although it's not faulty in itself.

They've just been talking about kmemcheck in LWN http://lwn.net/Articles/260068/ ... that could be of some help. Otherwise, review your own code, double-check every memory allocation and deallocation, study carefully the output of gcc -Wall and hunt for undefined pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for printk.  You might want to have a look at this introduction to [kernel debugging techniques](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch04.html).